# How to set Awesome as the default WM in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: window-manager, awesome, settings, defaults

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. I just downloaded Awesome and I'd like to start running it by default. I tried to open Awesome on the command line and received the message `E: awesome: main:772: another window manager is already running (can't select SubstructureRedirect)`. What does this mean/how can I set up Awesome as the default window manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to select it from the display manager aka lock screen, if you use gnome click on the top right corner and then click log out, after you log out select your user but before you enter your password, click the gear at the lower right of the screen, a menu will appear, select awesome, after that you can input your password and login, now you are using the awesome wm!